# How to make a bar plot like this with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to make a bar-plot like the picture below?

[image: Fig.1]

I've tried, but only can get this one:

[image: Fig.2]

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(N.Balance, aes(x = factor(Period), y = value)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes( group = Type, fill = variable), osition = "stack", width = 0.6) +
facet_wrap(~ Type,ncol = 1) +
coord_flip() +
scale_fill_grey() + 
theme_bw(base_size = 30, base_family = "serif") + 
labs(y = expression(paste("kg", " ", "N", " ", ha^{-1}))) + 
theme(legend.key.height = unit(0.5, "in"))
```

And the data is shown below:

```
structure(list(Period = c("2007R", "2007/2008W", "2008R", "2008/2009W", 
"2009R", "2009/2010W", "2007R", "2007/2008W", "2008R", "2008/2009W", 
"2009R", "2009/2010W", "2007R", "2007/2008W", "2008R", "2008/2009W", 
"2009R", "2009/2010W", "2007R", "2007/2008W", "2008R", "2008/2009W", 
"2009R", "2009/2010W", "2007R", "2007/2008W", "2008R", "2008/2009W", 
"2009R", "2009/2010W", "2007R", "2007/2008W", "2008R", "2008/2009W", 
"2009R", "2009/2010W", "2007R", "2007/2008W", "2008R", "2008/2009W", 
"2009R", "2009/2010W", "2007R", "2007/2008W", "2008R", "2008/2009W", 
"2009R", "2009/2010W", "2007R", "2007/2008W", "2008R", "2008/2009W", 
"2009R", "2009/2010W", "2007R", "2007/2008W", "2008R", "2008/2009W", 
"2009R", "2009/2010W"), 
variable = c("Denitrification", "Denitrification", "Denitrification", "Denitrification",
"Denitrification", "Denitrification", "Runoff", "Runoff", "Runoff", "Runoff", "Runoff", 
"Runoff", "Leaching", "Leaching", "Leaching", "Leaching", "Leaching", "Leaching", "NH3Vol", 
"NH3Vol", "NH3Vol", "NH3Vol", "NH3Vol", "NH3Vol", "Harvest", 
"Harvest", "Harvest", "Harvest", "Harvest", "Harvest", "Fertilizer", 
"Fertilizer", "Fertilizer", "Fertilizer", "Fertilizer", "Fertilizer", 
"Fix", "Fix", "Fix", "Fix", "Fix", "Fix", "Irrigation", "Irrigation", 
"Irrigation", "Irrigation", "Irrigation", "Irrigation", "Seeds", 
"Seeds", "Seeds", "Seeds", "Seeds", "Seeds", "Deposition", "Deposition", 
"Deposition", "Deposition", "Deposition", "Deposition"), 
value = c(-89.4, -34.4, -61.5, -82.5, -87.2, -34.7, -21.8, -33.4, -2.65, -42.8, 
-19.2, -58.7, -8.22, -1.44, -9.76, -4.76, -4.97, -19, -71.6, 
-50.8, -97.1, -10.9, -60.6, -19.6, -187, -116, -167, -96, -177, 
-127, 300, 200, 300, 200, 300, 200, 45, 15, 45, 15, 45, 15, 12.5, 
0, 11.6, 0, 11.3, 0, 0.9, 3, 0.9, 3, 0.9, 3, 8.41, 13.74, 4.01, 
13.34, 16.31, 9.81), Type = c("O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", 
"O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", 
"O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I")), 
.Names = c("Period", "variable", "value", "Type"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA,  -60L))
```

Note that the type "O" means "Output" and "I" means "Input"

Comment: Best way to get help and working code is to post minimal input data, and expected outcome inline here (instead of external links).

Comment: Why wld you want to replicate that monstrosity?

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I just want to know wheather ggplot2 can handle that kind of picture or not.

Comment: aye. it most definitely can.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, would you please give me some suggestion about how to make that? I really want to know that. Thanks

Comment: @Gopala, thank you for your kind suggestion.

Comment: Output of `dput(N.Balance)` would help (vs the head/tail)

Comment: @hrbrmstr,I've already ouput my whole data,frame (N.Balance). So,is it possible for you to give me a little help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would have been more helpful to do the `dput()` I asked for in the comment, but I replaced the `print()` output with that for others who may want to contribute.

There are (at a minimum) two other ways (than the one below) to get close to that chart. This one relies on an emerging new `geom_` that lets you have horizontal bars w/o `coord_flip()` - which means you can play with facet scales:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance) # devtools::install_github("lionel-/ggstance")
library(dplyr)

N.Balance <- read.csv("~/Data/so.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
N.Balance$Period_f <- factor(N.Balance$Period)
N.Balance$Type_f <- factor(N.Balance$Type, 
                         levels=c("O", "I"),
                         labels=c("Output", "Input"))

gg <- ggplot(N.Balance, aes(x=value, y=Period_f))
gg <- gg + geom_barh(stat = "identity", 
                    aes(group = Type, fill = variable), 
                    position = "stack", width = 0.6)
gg <- gg + geom_text(data=data.frame(Period=unique(N.Balance$Period)),
                     aes(x=5, y=Period, label=Period),
                     color="white", hjust=0, size=3)
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,-0.001))
gg <- gg + scale_fill_grey(name="")
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~ Type_f, ncol=2, scales="free_x")
gg <- gg + guides(fill=guide_legend(keywidth = 2, keyheight = 1))
gg <- gg + labs(y=NULL, x = expression(paste("kg", " ", "N", " ", ha^{-1})))
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.key.height = unit(0.5, "in"))
gg <- gg + theme(panel.background=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.border=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.margin=margin(l=0, r=0))
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="top")
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(strip.background=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(legend.key=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(legend.text=element_text(size=8))
gg <- gg + theme()
gg
```

[image]

This new `geom_barh()` is in a package that is not on CRAN (yet) so if that's an issue, there are—as I said—at least two other ways.

One other way gives you completely flush bars, and it's possible to do that w/just `geom_bar()` but it takes some data wrangling and axis text label wrangling. You have to hand craft what facet labeling gets you for free here (if you need the Input/Output labels).

If you need the legends separated (and some additional tweaking to get the bars flush), then most straighforward way is to make two separate plots, edit grob margins & use  `grid.arrange()`. This method can also get you aligned Input/Output labels if you do it in the plot title.

Both of those are "work".

If you need pattern fills, someone else will have to help you. That's doable but tedious.

Comment: Fantastic！Thanks for taking the time to respond to my question. The new `geom_barh()` seems great.

Comment: @ hrbrmstr, One more basic question: I'm a little confused about the parameter  `group` in `aes(group =)`. If ggplot handle the `geom_` by  different groups, why , in this case, `geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(group = Type, fill = variable))`  didn't give the expected output?  Apologize for my English. Hope you can understand what I'm asking.

Comment: it's more to do with how ggplot2 handles (or in this case, does not handle) both + & - with the `position="stack"`. It's only well-defined for >= 0 values and won't automatically do the alternating arrangement that you needed (i think this answers your question but i might have misunderstood).

Comment: Thank you for your time! It really helped me a lot!